# python script to read sqlite3 database is failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to `SELECT value of column_2 from the sqlite3 TABLE table_name WHERE, column_3 value is 'Waiting'`.

I want to pass column names, table_name and condition check value as variables .

I have written a script like this with class, but it failing .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
import re
   class Read_class(object):
      def __init__(self,db_name,table_name,status,column_to_read,column_state):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.status = status
        self.column_to_read = column_to_read
        self.column_state = column_state
      def read_waiting(self):
        db_name = self.db_name
        column_2 = self.column_to_read
        table_name = self.table_name
        column_3 = self.status
        print column_3
        column_state = self.column_state
        print column_state
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        print "Opened database successfully";
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT ({coi}) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn} = {cs}".\
          format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name, cn=column_3,cs=column_state))
        conn.commit()
        row = c.fetchall()
        print row
        return row
 C = Read_class('test.db', 'Test_Task', 'status', 'Task_ID','Waiting')
 task_id = C.read_waiting()
```

I am getting the following error :

```
 dccom@dccom-vm:~/auto/scripts$ python class.py
 status
 Waiting
 Opened database successfully
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "class.py", line 70, in <module>
 task_id = C.read_waiting()
 File "class.py", line 26, in read_waiting
 format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name, cn=column_3,cs=column_state))
 sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Waiting.

 My sqlite3 db schema and data stored on the db  is as follows:
 CREATE TABLE Test_Task
          (User_Name TEXT  NOT NULL,
           User_Email varchar(20),
           Image_Name varchar(30),
           UGW_Tag varchar(20),
           WAN_Mode varchar(10),
           Test_Type varchar(20),
           Sub_Type varchar(20),
           Task_ID  INT  NOT NULL,
           status varchar(20));
```

Data stored on the DB:

```
sqlite> SELECT * from Test_Task;        
nagesh|nag@gmail.com|20161020134234_CSX5000.tar|Ubuntu16.04xenial|WAN|SANITY|xxxxxi|1|Running
ramesh|ramesh@gamil.com|123_wan.tar|12ertf|LAN|FULL|aqbc|2|Waiting
vishal|vish@gmail.com|20161020135030_CSX5000.tar|Ubuntu16.04xenial|WAN|SANITY|xxxxxi|3|Running
ramesh|ramesh@gamil.com|123_wan.tar|12ertf|LAN|FULL|aqbc|4|Waiting
```

Please suggest how can achieve this.

Comment: what query  exactly you want to run?

Comment: I am trying to do the following commands using python script :
sqlite> SELECT Task_ID from Test_Task WHERE status = 'Waiting';
2
4
sqlite>  Where I m trying to pass Task_ID, Test_Task,status and Waiting as variables .

Comment: You should put an example of the database here as well

Comment: @Yugi : I have updated the database details.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your SQL and print it out you will quickly see that it contains `WHERE status = Waiting`.  You want it to contains `WHERE status = 'Waiting'` (notice the single quotes around the text string).  Your version causes SQL to look for the contents of a column named Waiting and compare that, not the string 'Waiting'.

The correct SQL to search for records where the column `status` contains the word Waiting is:

```
SELECT Task_ID FROM Test_Task WHERE status = 'Waiting'
```

but what you are generating is:

```
SELECT Task_ID FROM Test_Task WHERE status = Waiting
```

This second piece of SQL is searching for records where the columns `status` and `Waiting` have identical values.  Because table `Test_Task` does not contain a column named Waiting, SQLite is not able to interpret the SQL and produces the error you are seeing.

Note that the value your supplying should *not* be placed in the string by formatting (as your doing) but should be represented by a parameter and passed separately into execute.  This is because 1) if the value comes from user input SQL injection is possible and 2) it won't work if the value itself contains a single quote (as in the last name O'Malley, for instance).

You can also eliminate all the local variables in the method `read_waiting` and refer the instance values (`self.table_name`, etc) directly.

Comment: I don't want my result to be in format WHERE status = 'Waiting',  In my script I am trying to pass status and waiting both strings as variable .

Comment: if you see : c.execute("SELECT ({coi}) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn} = {cs}".\
          format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name,         cn=column_3,cs=column_state))
        conn.commit()

Comment: the value in the variable {cs} is getting assigned to variable {cn} while executing , I wanted the script to check whether {cn} = = {cs} , but unfortunately which is not happening . Hope u got clear idea of my issue :

Comment: Please go back and re-read my answer.  The error you are seeing (`no such column: Waiting`) is because you have not correctly quoted the string Waiting in the SQL that's generated from your formatted template string.  Fix that and then see if you have any more errors.

Comment: I tried by adding quotes in sqlite database as well, still hitting same issue . Could you please drop a line of code which i can use it here . it will be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I understood what was the issue . I tried the following code line and it worked for me .                            c.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE status = '%s'"%(column_2,table_name,column_state))